# Installing Openni kinect drivers

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am having trouble installing openni drivers.  When I follow the instructions "hg clone [https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers"](https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers%22) the response is: destination directory: drivers
abort: Permission denied.  If I got to the website https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers , it turns out to be a openni-drivers:log.  Ive tried several times over a period of time so now I'm not sure what to do.  I know that this issue was address last June, but answers given didn't help me out.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Gene

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12495/installing-openni-kinect-drivers/) by [GenePSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1562/genepsmith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where are you checking this code out on your computer?

Is suspect the error is on your side and you don't have writing permissions in the location that you are checking out. (It works for me without errors.)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1